# Springboot remove class only when deploy

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have one springboot project but I wanna to deploy in my nexus to use with component in another project, so I try to remove some classes just like this:

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>br.com.lumera.balcaoonline.api.BalcaoonlineApiApplication.class</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>br/com/lumera/balcaoonline/api/BalcaoonlineApiApplication.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>br/com/lumera/balcaoonline/api/central/controller/rtdpj/*.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/application-*.yml</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I need to remove the controllers and the main class, but now when I try to run the project the springboot dont find the main class

how can I fix this?

tks

Comment: I think it would be possible to create two jars: one for spring and one for nexus (without those classes) but I think it would be better to split it into multiple projects/modules

Comment: Why would you like to remove classes from a built artifact? Furthermore why have you changed the default directory via `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`? I strongly recommend to keep the defaults (convention over configuration paradigm)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use profiles to create one jar for nexus and another not for nexus.

**Maven command:**
mvn install -DwithNexus=true

**Example:**

```
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>withNexus</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>br.com.lumera.balcaoonline.api.BalcaoonlineApiApplication.class</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>br/com/lumera/balcaoonline/api/BalcaoonlineApiApplication.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>br/com/lumera/balcaoonline/api/central/controller/rtdpj/*.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/application-*.yml</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>no-nexus</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>withNexus</name>
            <value>!true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>br.com.lumera.balcaoonline.api.BalcaoonlineApiApplication.class</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```